# Hiding and showing a subnav when clicked and adding and removing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Think i may be getting a little confused:

I have 2 nav buttons, 1 of which has a subnav. When i click link 1 once this should add an active class to the li if not already active, on the second click you should be able to see the subnav. Link 2 is just a plain button, click it and you add active to the li and reset the Link 1 height.

I have a couple of problems, first off I want to reset the height of Link 1 if I click the Link 1 button when the subnav is visible then show it if clicked again etc. I also want to remove .active from Link 2 when I click Link 2? If someone could explain a much better way of completing this task that would be great, thanks!

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link1').click(function(e) {    
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('active') ) {
            $(this).parent().css('height', '90');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }

        // if i click again i want to reset css height to 45?
    });

    $('#link2').click(function(e) {
        if( !$(this).parent().hasClass('active') ) {
            $('#navigation > li').removeClass('active');
            $('#link1').parent().css('height', '45');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
        <ul id="inner">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Link to jsbin here http://jsbin.com/utuwor/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without all the ID's just controlling the sub navigation showing throw CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/J7aVC/1/

```
jQuery(function($) {  // This is a shorten for jQuery.ready and you are sure that $ === jQuery in this scope
    $("#navigation li > a").bind("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            hasActive = !!$this.parent(".active").length;

        if ( !hasActive ) {
            $this.closest("ul").find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $this.parent().andSelf().addClass("active");
        }
    });
});​
```

And your CSS:

```
#navigation li > ul {
    display:none;
}
#navigation li.active > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

And this works for lists in lists in lists in...

```
-> List1
    -> List1.1
    -> List1.2
        -> List1.2.1
            -> List 1.2.1.1
        -> List1.2.1
    -> List1.3
-> List2
```

etc...

---

### `E > E`, `!!`, `andSelf()`, `closest`:

**`E > E`** means that you search E for it's children E.

In your CSS you have:

```
#navigation li.active > ul
```

This means that any `ul`-tags that are a child of `li.active` becomes visible.

Take this example:

```
ul#navigation
    -> li.active
        -> ul // This is visible
            -> li
                -> ul // This is not
            -> li
    -> li
        -> ul // This is not
```

**`!!`** turns any String, Object, Integer, etc into a Boolean.

Any falsy value (`"", 0, null, undefined, false, NaN`) becomes `false`

**`andSelf()`** is a jQuery method that takes your filtered statement and includes it's original selector, It's the same as writing:

```
$(this).parent().add( this );

$(this).parent().andSelf();
```

But if you have a long selector it's nice:

```
$("#very .long .selector.we > .have .to.search").parent().add("#very .long .selector.we > .have .to.search");

$("#very .long .selector.we > .have .to.search").andSelf();
```

---

You use **`closest()`** to start beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.